# railsのルーティングがurlはあってそうなのにコントローラに通らない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

railsのwebアプリでいいね機能を実装したいです。
ルーティングが間違っているのか、chromeでlocalhostで検証していいねのボタンをクリックしたところ、ビューには何も変化はなく、コンソールでは

destroyメソッド =>
    POST http://localhost:3000/translations/103/likes/2 404 (Not Found)
createメソッド　=>
    POST http://localhost:3000/translations/104/likes 404 (Not Found)
となっており、ルーティングがうまく行ってないみたいなのですが、どこが悪いのかよく分かりません。
どなたか教えていただけませんか！！

likes controllerのdestroyのはじめにbinding.pryをつけても同じエラーなので、likes#destroy(またはcreate)にパスが通ってないみたいです、、

```
> routes.rb

　resources :translations do
    resources :likes, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end

> show.html.erb

<% @translations.each do |translation| %>
...
  <%= render "likes/like", translation:translation %>
...
<% end %>

> likes/_like.html.erb

<% if translation.like_user(@current_user.id) %>
            <%= button_to translation_like_path(translation_id: translation.id),
             method: :delete, id: "like-button", class: "btn-like",  remote: true do %>
            <%= image_tag('/icons/like-red.png') %>
<% end %>

<%= button_to translation_likes_path(translation_id: translation.id), id: "like-button", class: "btn-like", remote: true do %>
  <%= image_tag('/icons/like.png') %>
<% end %>
```

コンソールでrake routesすると、

```
translation_likes POST   /translations/:translation_id/likes(.:format)     likes#create
translation_like DELETE /translations/:translation_id/likes/:id(.:format) likes#destroy
```

となってます。

Comment: rake routes のPostのUrl はid が含まれていないように見えます。

Comment: わかりにくくてすみません、この場合:idを含むpostのurlがDELETEメソッドを表している感じだと思います。createメソッドのいいね！をクリックした時のコンソールの表示も追加してます。

Comment: config/route.rbとコンソールまたはdevelopment.logの内容を省略せずに追記してください。あとtranslation_like_pathのパラメータがおかしい(likeのidが渡されてない)のですがこれが本当のコードですか？

Answer (score -1):

log/development.log で当該アクセス近辺のログも出して頂けた方が、より適切な回答が得られる話のように見えます。
LikesController#create/destroy の情報取得周りとエラー処理なども、でしょうか。

提示されている情報では LikesController#create/destroy に回されている形に見えますが、例えば controller のコード側で「指定された ID の情報が見つからなかったら 404 を返す形にしている」の場合、ルーティングの失敗なのか指定された情報の読み込み失敗なのかが判別できません。

LikesController#create で Translation.find(params[:id]) 的な事をしていたら「そりゃ :translation_id じゃないと見つからないよね」ですし、#destroy の方でも :id と :translation_id の指定ミスなどもあり得ます。
「情報が見つからなかったら 404 にする」といったことは普通に行われるので、「なぜか 404 になる」は、経路設定だけではなくコード側の可能性もあるので、コントローラー周りのコードもないとコメントのしようがないと思いますよ。